# libGDX Scene2d - Use screen units to draw text on world coordinates

Tags: libgdx, stage, scene2d

Recently began learning scene2d and developed a card game with it. I used world units for my coordinate system whereby one card width is 1f. The center of the screen is (0, 0) using world units.
Now I'm trying to draw a label on the center card placed at (1,0) but it's showing extremely large, no matter how much i scale the font, and i can't scale less than 0.05f.

I did extensive research and found out [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/73688/why-is-my-text-is-too-large-even-when-scaled-to-05f-in-libgdx) that i can use `camera.project` for this, tried but couldn't work quite well. I'd appreciate any examples.

The goal is to temporarily project my world coordinates to screen coordinates, draw the text at the required position and with the correct size(in screen pixels), then unproject the stage back to world units, and continue further processes.

I'd show code if asked to, but i really just require some guidance here.

Comment: Your card is sprite or a scene2d element?

Comment: My card is a scene2d element, all actors

Comment: You could use a separate stage, viewport, or camera (pick your favorite) that is fit to the screen and use that to draw text on top of the stage with your game actors.

Comment: Wouldn't the stage on top hinder the clickability of the views in the stage behind?